# cannot import class, even though quick fix founds it

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In my code I use the not yet imported class `NoSuchElementException`. If I select the class and do  "import class" or "expand class", I get "The class is not found.".

But VS code proposes a fix (yellow bulb), and if I click on it, it imports the class at the top :

`from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException`

If VS code can find the class, why "import class" does not find it ?

Even with a simple class name like "By", vscode quickly finds the possible classes, and I do "quick fix" :

[image: vscode quick fix]

But I'd like to do something like "import class" or "expand class" myself, instead of using "quick fix".

Answer (score 1):

VS Code has scanned all of the modules it can find and has built up a database of possible solutions. It takes a guess on what you might want and shows it to you. This is rather computation intensive, which is fine when you are editing in an IDE, but burdensome for every load of a python program. And the guess is just that: a guess. You can't fully automate something that is so prone to error. Its reasonable to think that multiple packages would implement something called "NoSuchElementException". What about something really common such as "Path" or "Application"?

Python has a set of rules about namespaces and where modules are stored on disk to avoid ambiguities at runtime.

Comment: IDE's have gotten so "helpful" that I avoid them whenever possible.

Comment: But even with a simple class like "By", vscode finds the possible classes, and I do "quick fix". Bu I'd like to do something like "import class" or "expand class" myself, instead of using "quick fix". I updated my post with a screenshot.

Comment: @trogne - But in the end, its just a guess. Suppose that you install this program on a different machine that has another package with a "By" - you crash with no obvious reason why. VSCode simply marking "By" as undefined is sufficient - you should know which package its from when you decided to use it - the extra suggestion is helpful a bit. But the guess could be wrong, and you still have to know what it should be. But how about when someone else looks at your code, or next year when you forgot what you did. "By" without an import to tell you what package you were using is not helpful.

Comment: Ok. I'll stick with using the "quick fix" (ctrl+.). VSCode is very good at that. I would have thought that what VSCode do when using "quick fix", is something else that have its own command (like "import class" or else).

Comment: There may be a module out there that does this or you could write your own, post it on pypi.python.org and see if it gains traction. You don't want to actually load all of the modules on the system, but some sort of a lexical scan would give you information. I think its a terrible idea, but that's only one opinion. You can let the marketplace decide.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the multiple folders in the python directory installed on your computer. The folder which you try to import is deep in the python directory. If you use `Import NoSuchElementException` the program can't find it because it doesn't goes as deep as it needs to be to find the folder.

That's why you need to specify `selenium.common.exceptions`. So the program knows in which folders to search for `NoSuchElementException`

I hope this answer helps you.